# A null value was found for the property named - OData serialization issue

Tags: c#, odata

I'm querying an SAP OData system to get all records and data for a certain entity. The problem I'm running into with this specific entity is that some 'non-nullable' fields seem to have null values and it throws an error thus breaking the entire operation. The error happens at the foreach, I'm assuming as it starts to deserialize the results into the Candidate class:

```
A null value was found for the property named 'dateofAvailability', which has the expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values. ---> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: A null value was found for the property named 'dateofAvailability', which has the expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.
```

Code below:

```
System.Type t = typeof(SFOData.Candidate);
                List<string> fields = new List<string>();
                string fieldString = "";
                if (t != null)
                {
                    fields = t.GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
                }
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    if (field != "anonymizedDateTime" && field != "password" && field != "agreeToPrivacyStatement" && field != "dataPrivacyId" && field != "privacyAcceptDateTime")
                    {
                        fieldString += (field + ",");
                    }
                }
                fieldString.TrimEnd(',');

                var results = context.Candidate.AddQueryOption("$skip", skip).AddQueryOption("$inlinecount", "allpages").AddQueryOption("$select", fieldString);

                var resultsRaw = await results.ExecuteAsync();

                int blockCount = 0;
                foreach (var result in resultsRaw.Item2)
                {
                    allCandidates.Add(result);
                    blockCount++;
                }
```